# Proof $x\to ||f(x)||_B \in \mathbb{L}^1(X,S,\mu,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Why is the function $g:x\to ||f(x)||_B$ in  $\mathbb{L}^1(X,S,\mu,\mathbb{R})$, where $f\in\mathbb{L}^1(X,S,\mu,\mathbb{R})$, and $||\cdot||_B$ is the norm in the Banach space that $f$ maps into? I feel like it should be a simple argument, but I don't know how to proceed. Because $f\in \mathbb{L}^1(X,S,\mu,\mathbb{R})$ we know that there is a sequence of measurable simple functions $\{f_n\}$ that converges a.e. to $f$ that is mean Cauchy, but I'm not sure how to go from that to the Banach Space norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_n \colon X \to B$ be simple functions in $L^1(X, B)$ such that $\|f - f_n\|_1 \to 0$. Define $g_n \colon X \to \mathbf R$ by $g_n(x) := \def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\norm{f_n(x)}_B$. Then $g_n$ is a measurable (as the norm is continuous, hence measurable) simple function from $X$ to $\mathbf R$. Moreover 
\begin{align*}
  \norm{g_n - g}_{L^1(X,\def\R{\mathbf R}\R)} &= \int_{X}\left|\norm{f_n(x)}_B - \norm{f(x)}_B\right| \, dx\\
    &\le \int_{X}\norm{f_n(x) - f(x)}_B\, dx\\
    &= \norm{f_n - f}_{L^1(X, B)} \to 0
\end{align*}
Hence, $g\in L^1(X, \R)$.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, $g$ is measurable because it is the composition of the measurable function $f$ with the continuous function $y\longmapsto\|y\|_B$. And
$$
\int |g|\,d\mu=\int\|f\|_B\,d\mu=\|f\|_1<\infty,
$$
so $g\in L^1(X,\mu)$.